# Does SQL Server really evaluate every 'then' clause in a case expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with an ItemNumber field in a legacy system that is 99% numbers, but there are a few records that contain letters.  The numbers are all padded with leading zeros so I thought I would just cast them as bigint's to solve this problem, but of course it throws an error when it gets to the records with letters in them.

I thought the following case statement would have worked, but it still throws the error.  Why in the world is SQL Server evaluating the cast if the isnumeric(itemnumber) = 1 condition isn't true?

```
select case when isnumeric(itemnumber) = 1 
           then cast(itemnumber as bigint) 
           else itemnumber 
       end ItemNumber
from items
```

And what's the best workaround?

Comment: Would you please share the error message with us?

Comment: @Quassnoi Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: Because the result of the `CASE` has to be *a* type. What type should it be? You have a `bigint` and you have a `varchar`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please post some sample data and desired output

Comment: @ta.speot.is Thanks! I added another cast to turn it back to a varchar and it works perfect now.

Comment: @BrandonMoore But if `itemnumber` is already `varchar` that would make the `CASE` mostly redundant.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Except that now there are no leading 0's :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression tries to convert a `VARCHAR` value into a `BIGINT` if it's numeric and leave the value as is if it's not.

Since you are mixing datatypes in the `CASE` statement, `SQL Server` tries to cast them all into `BIGINT` but fails on non-numeric values.

If you just want to omit non-numeric values, get rid of the `ELSE` clause:

```
SELECT  CASE ISNUMERIC(itemnumber)
        WHEN 1 THEN
                CAST(itemnumber AS BIGINT) 
        END
FROM    items
```

Comment: +1 This man knows how to SQL Server. And for what it's worth, the rules for determining the return type of a `CASE` expression is can be learned about here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx *Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. For more information, see Data Type Precedence*

Comment: I solved the problem by casting the bigint back to a varchar.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: this will cast your numeric values first to int then back to varchar, and leave non-numeric as is. What was the purpose of the `CASE` in the first place, what problem did you want to solve with it? Did you just try to get rid of leading zeroes of what?

Comment: @Quassnoi Yeah, I just want to get rid of the leading zeros.  I'm preparing data from an old system to be imported into a new one but the new one truncates the end of the field if it's too long so I just needed to remove the leading zeros so that doesn't happen.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: ah ok then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because:

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($). For a complete list of currency symbols, see money and smallmoney (Transact-SQL).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Comment: This might be related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx *Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. For more information, see Data Type Precedence*

Comment: Thanks.  The problem isn't that it's giving a false positive for edge cases though, there are only a few records that are non-numeric and they just contain letters from a-z.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are still mixing your types:

```
select case when isnumeric(itemnumber) = 1 
           then cast(itemnumber as bigint) --bigint
           else itemnumber --varchar or whatever 
       end ItemNumber --????
from items
```

You need two columns

```
select case when isnumeric(itemnumber) = 1 
           then cast(itemnumber as bigint) --bigint
           else -1 
       end NumericItemNumber 
from items

select case when isnumeric(itemnumber) = 1 
           then ''
           else itemnumber
       end StringItemNumber 
from items
```

Then you need to build a query that takes both ints and varchars